# MobaXterm : How to import session database of PuttyCM

Tags: putty, mobaxterm

I am currently using **PuttyCM**  based on Putty to store sessions , urls and keys .

I'm ow switching to **MobaXterm** , and i want to import my database session to my MobaXterm menu .

Is there any way to handle it ?